# Ascii Value Randomly Changing in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to create an encryptor in C with the following algorithm I thought of. But, for some reasons it is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void 
encrypt(
    char word[],
    char password[]
)
{
    char res[strlen(word)];
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++){
        temp = (int) word[i];
        temp = temp + (int) password[i % strlen(password)];
        temp = (temp - 30)/2;
        res[i] = (char) temp;
    }
    printf("%s\n", res);
}

void decrypt(
    char word[],
    char password[]
)
{
    char res[strlen(word)];
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++){
        temp = (int) word[i];
        temp = temp * 2;
        temp = temp + 30;
        temp = temp - (int) password[i % strlen(password)];
        res[i] = (char) temp;
    }
    printf("%s\n", res);
}

int main(void) {
    encrypt("Hello World", "main");
    decrypt("KT[^_1Q_`WW", "main");
  return 0;
}
```

I got the following output

```
Output : 
KT[^_1Q_`WW
GekloWnqkc
```

I noticed that some of the text are matching while some got + 1 somehow but i am unable to figure out how.
While The decrypted text should be Hello World. I am new in programming and started with C. How can I fix this ?

Comment: You haven't allocated room for the null terminator in the local arrays so the program will crash if you treat them like strings. You need to do `strlen(...) + 1`.

Comment: @Lundin The problem here is not only that.

Comment: I close this as a duplicate to the "how to use strings" FAQ. If you still have bugs after fixing those basic problems, then please post a new question with the corrected code.

Comment: Thank you for your help in that. But that did not quite solve my problem. Do you have any more idea why that is happening ?

Comment: @MikeCAT Probably not but there's no point in posting yet another "here's how you do utterly fundamental string handling in C" answer. While the answer is essentially "read the string chapter of any beginner-level book". So generally the OP has to fix those bugs, then get back with the fixed code as a separate question.

Comment: Instead of simply posting the code of your algorithm's implementation, you should also describe your algorithm. That way, people can advise you if they determine your code doesn't actually implement the algorithm correctly, or if the algorithm itself will not achieve what you want.

Comment: `GekloWnqkc` is effectively `Geklo<31>Wnqkc` with the `<31>` ASCII unprintable character replacing the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your encrypt/decrypt error (for string error read comments) is that division by 2 is not reversible, ie `16/2` == `17/2` == `8`.

When you take `8` and want to decrypt it... you have no way to know if it was originally a `16` or a `17`.

Answer (score -1):

When you encrypt, you need to use the multiplication, because, anything times two, will result in an even number. So, the division by two, will result in the same number ...

This, might help you
Obs: This will not work with non ascii chars...

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void decrypt (
    char word[],
    char password[]
) {
    int temp;
    int size = strlen(word);
    int pass_size = strlen(password);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        temp = (int) word[i];
        temp = temp / 2 - 30 ;
        temp = temp + (int) password[i % pass_size];
        word[i] = (char) temp;
    }
}

void encrypt (
    char word[],
    char password[]
) {
    int temp;
    int size = strlen(word);
    int pass_size = strlen(password);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        temp = (int) word[i];
        temp = temp - (int) password[i % pass_size];
        temp = (temp + 30) * 2;
        word[i] = (char) temp;
    }
}

int main (
    int argc, 
    char** args    
) {

    char *dup = strdup(args[1]);
    
    encrypt(dup, "sgtcortez");

    printf("Encrypted: %s\n", dup);

    decrypt(dup, "sgtcortez");

    printf("Decrypted: %s\n", dup);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, @ChefGladiator, I didnt get it.

Comment: Is you comment related that my code will not work with non ascii chars?

Comment: @sgcorez my comment is related to a refactored version of your code.  your code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/97Kje6TfT)

Comment: actualy [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9qo9hTb3n) ... does not depend on `argv[1]`